# Edit overridden by high-rep user

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I just recently suggested an edit to a particular question, which was pending review, and then noticed a little later that the question had been updated following an edit. This was not my edit, but rather the edit of another user who has sufficiently high rep (+10,000) so that edits by this user are applied automatically. My issue is that the current edit actually continues to have some spelling issues. Shouldn't this user have been notified that an edit was already pending? It seems odd to me that someone would disregard a perfectly good edit (I spent some time making sure that I didn't leave any issues of my own; <s>however I don't have access to my edit anymore to show that it is in fact an improvement over the current one</s>) for a lower-quality one, which required them to take the time to fix up the question themselves.

Now, <strike>the typos introduced are relatively minor</strike>, but it's just bothering me that my own edit was ignored. Shouldn't such a user see that the question has been edited, review the edit, accept it if it's good, and fix it if there are still any issues? What has happened here is that the edit is completely different from the original, so that it is apparent that the original was completely ignored.

Is this just carelessness on the part of the particular user? Or is it possible that a +3000 rep user can edit a post without realizing that there is one already in the queue?

Comment: Related:  [Why allow multiple parallel edits but accept only one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21314/) //"Or is it possible that a +3000 rep user can edit a post without realizing that there is one already in the queue?" It is possible, but in this case the situation seems more complex.

Comment: [Edit suggestion](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/601366). You can reach it from your profile, the "all actions" tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The situation is this: a user reviewed your edit and decided to pick "Reject and Edit" (another user had approved your edit).

While I think your edit was not perfectly complete, I feel to "reject and edit" was just not the right decision here, and instead they should have selected "Improve Edit" to perform additional changes.

It is however also possible that users inadvertently over-ride edits, when they edit at the very same time, but this is then shown differently.  You can fiind more information on the main meta site [Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits)

Comment: [Case in point](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/551113) about the edits being overridden by a subsequent one (and how it appears in the history).

Comment: Even if an edit was partially good, sometimes it is easier to change the original source into the desired form than the suggested edit. In such situations I tend to use Reject and Edit because I care more about improving the post efficiently than about the small SE review game surrounding the process. (This is just an addendum; it doesn't apply to the current situation.)

Comment: @silvascientist see http://math.stackexchange.com/users/108405/silvascientist?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: @silvascientist Go to your profile, find "activity," then "all actions," then "suggestions."

Comment: @T.Bongers Oookay, I just didn't realize that information was available to everyone.